# Populate object graph native query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a parent -> child (one-to-many) relationship in my data model.  I need to select all children of a certain type and then group the children (in order) by their parent.  For example:

Parent (name="B")
- Child (type = 1)
- Child (type = 2)
- Child (type = 1)

-Parent (name="A")
 -Child (type = 1)

e.g. select all children of type 1 and join in their parent.

As I need to join in some other (calculated) data, the query needs to be SQL. My challenge is now grouping the data for presentation.  I need it grouped by parent.  It would be ideal if I could re-use my domain objects. e.g. convert:

Row 1: Parent A | child (type 1)
Row 2: Parent B | child (type 1)
Row 3: Parent B | child (type 1)

to:

-Parent (name="A")
 -Child (type = 1)

Parent (name="B")
- Child (type = 1)
- Child (type = 1)

Any suggestions on how to do this?  I want to use either JPA or Spring JDBC Template.  I know I can manually assemble / group the data myself, but I'm curious if there's a better way to do it, perhaps using a SqlResultSetMapper or a RowMapper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that relationship is One To Many when it comes to Parent --> Child. But when it comes to Child --> Parent the cardinality seems to be the One To Many too. Is the cardinality right? I can help you if you can be more clear on the relationship

Comment: It's a one-to-many (parent to children) and a many-to-one (children to parent).  I'm selecting the results by the children (of a certain type) and I want to group them by parent.